# NSDictionary's key value is not equal to the set key

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsdictionary

I am creating an image editing app for OS X. I have the following code that basically returns the window associated with a given image, and creates one if no window is created for that image yet:

```
+(TNRWindow*)windowForImage:(NSImage*)img{
    static NSMutableDictionary *imageMapping;
    static int uidCounter;
    if(!imageMapping){
        imageMapping = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    }
    TNRWindow *window = [imageMapping objectForKey:img];
    if(!window){
        window = [[TNRWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 800, 720) styleMask:(NSResizableWindowMask|NSTitledWindowMask|NSClosableWindowMask) backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
        [window center];
        window.uid = [NSNumber numberWithInt:uidCounter++];
        [imageMapping setObject:window forKey:img];
    }
    return window;

}
```

I've seen this method returning a new, different window at consecutive calls at it with the same `NSImage` instance. I've analyzed the code and realized that `[imageMapping setObject:window forKey:img];` doesn't set the right key. When I step over that line, it creates a key value pair, but the key is different from the `img` object.

Here is the `img` object:

```
(lldb) po img
<NSImage 0x600000078fc0 Size={1311.5999999999999, 875} Reps=(
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x6100000ba4c0 Size={1311.5999999999999, 875} 
     ColorSpace=sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace BPS=16 BPP=48 
     Pixels=5465x3646 Alpha=NO Planar=NO Format=0 
     CurrentBacking=<CGImageRef: 0x6180003a31e0> CGImageSource=0x61000016c900"
)>
```

Here is the key right after I set the dictionary entry:

```
(lldb) po [[imageMapping keyEnumerator] allObjects]
<__NSArrayM 0x618000255930>(
<NSImage 0x610000279440 Size={1311.5999999999999, 875} Reps=(
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x6180000baca0 Size={1311.5999999999999, 875} 
    ColorSpace=sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace BPS=16 BPP=48 
    Pixels=5465x3646 Alpha=NO Planar=NO Format=0 
    CurrentBacking=<CGImageRef: 0x6180003a31e0> CGImageSource=0x61000016c900"
)>
)
```

The objects themselves, and the `NSBitmapImageRep`s are different, but the backing `CGImageRef` and `CGImageSource` are the same. The object appears to be perfectly valid, but when I call `[imageMapping objectForKey:img];` it's returning me `nil` as the image object itself is not a key in the dictionary. There are no multiple threads that are calling this method. What is exactly going on here and how can I correct this behavior?

Comment: I can't imagine that using an image for a dictionary key is going to work very well.  You're depending on `isEqual` returning true for images which *you* define as equal, but there's no guarantee that your definition matches the actual one.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand how NSDictionary works. It used to work well previously whenever I set keys for different objects. I also come from C# background where setting a key in a dictionary just simply added the address of that object, so it's quite normal to expect this behavior.

Comment: You have to understand that any such scheme depends on having an `isEqual` method that will detect as equal objects which you regard as equal.  For simple objects like strings it's a no-brainer, but for it to work on something like an image requires that an object-specific `isEqual` method be defined, and that it check the same things you'd check.  If there is no object-specific `isEqual` implementation (and the spec does not indicate that there is) then `isEqual` falls back to simply checking for pointer equality.

Comment: I've got that part. What I didn't get was that the original object's pointer not being added and a copy being added to the dictionary. Now I've got it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSDictionary` copies keys — the following text is repeated quite often throughout the documentation:

> Each key is copied (using copyWithZone:; keys must conform to the
>   NSCopying protocol), and the copy is added to the new dictionary.

Keys are subsequently compared by value, not by identity. So the different addresses are exactly what's meant to happen.

I'll bet that `NSImage` doesn't implement `isEqual:` so as to match copies. So you'll need to use something other than `NSImage` as your key.

If you just want to comapre by identity, not by value, you can use `NSValue` via `+valueWithNonretainedObject:`.

E.g.

```
....
    NSValue *key = [NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:img];
    TNRWindow *window = [imageMapping objectForKey:key];
    if(!window){
        ...
        [imageMapping setObject:window forKey:key];
    }
```

EDIT: `NSDictionary` and `CFDictionary` are toll-free bridged and you can specify custom functions for almost every thing at the Core Foundation level, which would allow you to create an NSDictionary that retained keys instead of copying. It really depends what level you're happiest working at.

Comment: I see.. using NSValue did the trick. Yes, I just needed to compare the addresses

Answer (score 2):

You could associate a window with an `NSImage` directly using `objc_setAssociatedObject()`

You could implement is with a category on NSImage, like this:

Interface:

```
@interface NSImage (AssociatedWindow)
@property ( nonatomic, weak ) NSWindow * associatedWindow ; // change to strong if appropriate
@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation NSImage (AssociatedWindow)
@dynamic associatedWindow ;
-(void)setAssociatedWindow:(NSWindow*)window
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject( self, kAssociatedWindowKey, window, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN ) ; // assume you want a weak ref, otherwise use OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC
}

-(NSWindow*)associatedWindow
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject( self, kAssociatedWindowKey ) ;
}

-(NSWindow*)ensureAssociatedWindow
{
    NSWindow * result = self.associatedWindow ;
    if ( !result )
    {
        NSWindow * newWindow = // create window
        self.associatedWindow = newWindow ;
        result = newWindow ;
    }
    return result ;
}    
@end
```

Use like this: `NSWindow * theWindow = [ theImage ensureAssociatedWindow ]`

Comment: I'll be looking into that, any reason why my code behaves that way?